# angular js http get basic auth

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

Hi. At the beginning I have an auth page will just return a json code without doing any auth and then I tried the following code but without the basic auth line. It did work, but then once I added basic auth required on auth page access and I use the below code, then it didn't work. The console log test return status empty string.

When I used postman in chrome and it worked if I included the header auth. I can see the return json code. What's wrong with my code below? Thanks.

```
angular.module('demoApp')
  .controller('MyrouteCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {


    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic mybase64code';
    var output = $http.get('http://tmydomain.com:1338/auth/').
    then(function(response) {
            var status = response;
    });
    console.log("test", status );
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have `console.log` inside the response handler, e.g.

```
var output = $http.get('http://tmydomain.com:1338/auth/', [headers: [Authorization: 'Basic mybase64code']]).
then(function(response) {
        var status = response;
        console.log("test", status );
        return response.data;
});
```